# How can I change the name of adjacent specifiers all together by changing only one line in VS2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

[image]

I want to change, for example, all four *(not all occurrences, only these four)* `Vector3` specifiers into `Vector2` **only by editing one line** <sub>(bottom line in this case)</sub>**?**. Is there a way to do this in Visual Sudio 2013 Community Edition?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [MultiEditing Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2beb9705-b568-45d1-8550-751e181e3aef).  This allows you to select the four locations and make the same changes in each location.

Comment: Just a note that in larger files/projects, this extension can significantly slow down the entire editor. I don't understand why the problem appears, i.e. what can be so demanding under the hood of the extension. But for smaller stuff it works like a charm.